# How can I use a saveAsTextFile() function in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I am new in Spark, and I have some problems to register informations in a file.

The problem is the following:

I have declared the avglens RDD with the following command:

```
var avglens = sc.textFile("C:/Program Files/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/README.md")
.flatMap(line => line.split(' '))
.map(word => (word(0), word.length))
.groupByKey()
.map(pair => (pair._1, pair._2.sum/pair._2.size.toDouble))
```

then, I wanted to save informations of my avglens RDD in a new file named avglens-output.
To do that, I have launched the following command:

```
avglens.saveAsTextFile("avglen-output")
```

But, it returns the following error:

```
    21/06/17 13:15:44 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)/ 2]
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
        at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps$.apply$extension(StringOps.scala:41)
        at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.$anonfun$avglens$2(<console>:24)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:156)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
21/06/17 13:15:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) (192.168.1.20 executor driver): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
        at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps$.apply$extension(StringOps.scala:41)
        at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.$anonfun$avglens$2(<console>:24)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:156)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

21/06/17 13:15:44 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
21/06/17 13:15:44 ERROR SparkHadoopWriter: Aborting job job_202106171315432560914192953511091_0007.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) (192.168.1.20 executor driver): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
        at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps$.apply$extension(StringOps.scala:41)
        at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.$anonfun$avglens$2(<console>:24)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:156)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2253)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2202)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2201)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2201)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1078)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1078)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1078)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2440)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2382)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2371)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:868)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2202)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2223)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2255)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1090)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1088)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1061)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1026)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$3(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1008)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1007)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$2(PairRDDFunctions.scala:964)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:962)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$2(RDD.scala:1578)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1578)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1(RDD.scala:1564)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1564)
        at $line18.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:26)
        at $line18.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:30)
        at $line18.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:32)
        at $line18.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:34)
        at $line18.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:36)
        at $line18.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:38)
        at $line18.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:40)
        at $line18.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:42)
        at $line18.$read.<init>(<console>:44)
        at $line18.$read$.<init>(<console>:48)
        at $line18.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line18.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at $line18.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
        at $line18.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:745)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1021)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$interpret$1(IMain.scala:574)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:41)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:37)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:41)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:600)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:570)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:894)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:762)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:464)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:485)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:951)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1030)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
        at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps$.apply$extension(StringOps.scala:41)
        at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.$anonfun$avglens$2(<console>:24)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:156)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
21/06/17 13:15:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (192.168.1.20 executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
  at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1090)
  at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1088)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1061)
  at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1026)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$3(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1008)
  at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1007)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$2(PairRDDFunctions.scala:964)
  at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:962)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$2(RDD.scala:1578)
  at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1578)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1(RDD.scala:1564)
  at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1564)
  ... 47 elided
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) (192.168.1.20 executor driver): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
        at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps$.apply$extension(StringOps.scala:41)
        at $anonfun$avglens$2(<console>:24)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:156)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2253)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2202)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2201)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2201)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1078)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1078)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1078)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2440)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2382)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2371)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:868)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2202)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2223)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2255)
  at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:83)
  ... 83 more
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
  at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps$.apply$extension(StringOps.scala:41)
  at $anonfun$avglens$2(<console>:24)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)
  at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:156)
  at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Also, a new folder avglens-output is created in my `C:\Program Files\spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin` folder, but it is empty.

I don't understand why this errors appears, I have however authorized the writing on the bin folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be in the map with `word(0)`, not in the saveAsTextFile.

Since you are doing the split in the `flatMap`, the output of that step is a RDD with each word as a row, there is not an array for each element, just single word.

FlatMap flattens the array.

Check the difference

**flatMap**

```
  scala> val rdd =  sc.textFile("/Users/my_name/Workspace/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/README.md").flatMap(line => line.split(' '))

    
    scala> rdd.take(5).foreach(println)
    #
    Apache
    Spark

    Spark
```

**map**

```
scala> val rdd =  sc.textFile("/Users/sergio.couto/Workspace/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/README.md").map(line => line.split(' '))

scala> rdd.take(5).foreach(println)
[Ljava.lang.String;@7cd1d235
[Ljava.lang.String;@1736262a
[Ljava.lang.String;@7252e063
[Ljava.lang.String;@5edd0a7e
[Ljava.lang.String;@2c6f2bea
```

So you don't need to do word(0), it's not an array, you can just do `word => (word, word.length)`

**Full Example:**

```
val rdd =  sc.textFile("/Users/my_name/Workspace/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/README.md")
      .flatMap(line => line.split(' '))
      .map(word => (word, word.length))
      .groupByKey()
      .map(pair => (pair._1, pair._2.sum/pair._2.size.toDouble))


scala> rdd.take(10).foreach(println)
(package,7.0)
(this,4.0)
(integration,11.0)
(Python,6.0)
(cluster.,8.0)
(its,3.0)
([run,4.0)
(There,5.0)
(general,7.0)
(YARN,,5.0)
```

Then you will be able to perform `saveAsTextFile` or whichever method you need